# The file was not uploaded due to an unknown error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to upload same image for multiple students. It works for first one but for next one it gives error.
my code

```
foreach($student_ids as $key => $student_id) {

        $fileIds='';
        if(Input::hasfile('attachment')){
            $comment = $comments[0];
            $file = Input::file('attachment');
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/moments/'.$student_id;
            $filename = "moment_".time()."_".trim(rand(1,999)).".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            if(is_dir($destinationPath)) {
                $upload_success =  $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
            }else {
                if(mkdir($destinationPath)) {
                    $upload_success =  $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);    
                }
            }
            $file = Moment_gallery::create(['image'=>$filename,'comment'=>$comment]);
            $fileIds.=$file->id.',';                        
        }

        $moments = new moment();
        $moments->activity_id = $activity;
        $moments->type=$activity_type;
        $moments->student_id=$student_id;           
        $moments->date = $date;
        $moments->time = $activity_time ? $activity_time : ' ';
        $moments->save();
    }
```

here i am getting array of multiple students id... So i am just uploading same image for those students. It works for single student but then for multiple students it works for first one and give error for second one as

```
FileException in UploadedFile.php line 235:The file "student.png" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.
```

whats wrong..? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = Input::file('attachment');
```

Understanding that $file is of object type:

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile
```

and that it's pointing at the file on the server, e.g.

```
e‌‌cho $file->getRealPath(); // ‌/tmp/phpp6HYIk
```

then you can see that by performing:

```
$file->move($dest_path);
```

you're moving the file away from it's original destination thereby making it unavailable for subsequent iterations.